# Blit transparent images with Allegro

Tags: c++, image, transparency, draw, allegro

I'm wondering if there is any possibility to draw png with transparent colors, so I can make something half-transparent. I've read [this](http://www.allegro.cc/manual/4/api/transparency-and-patterned-drawing/) but I can't get anything to work. I also heard about alpng library but I don't know if it's able to load transparency too.
I'm using `allegro 4.2.1` with the newest `Dev-C++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load a 32-bit image, call `set_alpha_blender()` and then `draw_trans_sprite()`. See [this discussion](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/589076). TGA is the only format that Allegro 4 supports natively that is sufficient for this task. Otherwise, you'll need to look into a PNG loader add-on.

You may also want to consider switching to Allegro 5 if you are just getting started. It has a much more modern API for this type of thing.

Comment: I like allegro 4, and I think 5 is too simmilar to SDL. I like allegro for being so easy, and allegro 5 is much more complex than 4. anyway, thx for help.

Comment: And how about drawing on this tga?

Comment: I mean putpixel, rectfill aso.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "drawing on this tga". (If you have another question, you should start a new question.)

Comment: I solved it myslef, I meant drawing with alpha channel, how to COPY the alpha just like it is, and how to ADD colors.